# How to fix "Unhandled exception" error in assembly?

Tags: function, assembly, x86, primes, masm

I've written a function that determines if a value is prime or not prime. But when I return from the function, it comes up with an error.
The error message is

> Unhandled exception at 0x00000001 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000001.

This function should return `eax`.

```
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov eax, [ebp+8]                ; store input value
        mov ecx, [ebp+8]                ; store input value in counter
        sub esp, 4                      ; local variable 
        sub ecx, 1                      ; avoid compare with itself
        cmp eax, 3                      ; compare with 1, 2, 3
        jbe Prime

    L1:
        cmp ecx, 3                      ; when count=3 to stop
        je NotP
        mov edx, 0                      ; clear edx to save remainder
        mov [esp-4], eax                ; save input value
        div ecx                         ; divide number
        cmp edx, 0                      ; check remainder
        je NotP                         ; if remainder=0 then not prime
        jmp Prime
        loop L1
    NotP:
        mov eax, 0
        push eax                        ; if delete this ilne still come up error
        pop ebp
        ret
    Prime:
        mov eax, 1                      
        push eax                        ; if delete this ilne still come up error
        pop ebp
        ret
    isPrime  endp
```

Comment: What error? Include that in your post. EDIT: The `push eax` instruction before the function epilog is suspicious. What happens if you omit that line?

Comment: What are the parameters which cause the exception?

Comment: I omit that line still comes up with the same error.

Comment: You aren't cleaning up the stack correctly (ie your epilog code is wrong).  In addition to removing the push eax, you also need to [restore esp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/considerations-for-writing-prolog-epilog-code?view=vs-2019), otherwise you are "returning" to the value in your local variable.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    mov [esp-4], eax                ; save input value
> ```

If you plan on using the local variable that you reserved room for, then you have to write:

```
    mov [esp], eax                ; save input value
```

or alternatively write:

```
    mov [ebp-4], eax              ; save input value
```

---

A correct prolog/epilog would be:

```
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4                 ; local variable 
    mov     eax, [ebp+8]           ; store input value

    ...

NotP:
    mov     eax, 0
    pop     ebp                    ; remove local variable
    pop     ebp
    ret
Prime:
    mov     eax, 1                      
    pop     ebp                    ; remove local variable
    pop     ebp
    ret
isPrime  endp
```

---

> ```
>     cmp edx, 0                      ; check remainder
>     je NotP                         ; if remainder=0 then not prime
>     jmp Prime
>     loop L1
> ```

Finding the remainder not zero is not enough to conclude that the number is prime! More tests are needed. For now, that `loop L1` instruction is never executed.
e.g. To test 15, your first division does 15 / 14 which yields a non-zero remainder but 15 isn't a prime number.

> ```
> L1:
>     cmp ecx, 3                      ; when count=3 to stop
>     je NotP
> ```

The top of the loop can't be correct either! Consider testing the number 7.
First division is 7 / 6 and has a remainder so the loop has to continue
Second division is 7 / 5 and has a remainder so the loop has to continue
Third division is 7 / 4 and has a remainder so the loop has to continue
You don't try any more divisions and conclude "not prime", yet 7 is definitively a prime number.

Comment: Is `pop ebp` really the best way to remove the local variable?  Modifies 2 registers and performs a memory read.  It also doesn't work well if you need more (or less) than 1 local int.  How about just `mov esp, ebp`?

Comment: @DavidWohlferd As the prime-numbers-algorithm was already disastrously inefficient, I wasn't focussed on efficiency at all. *"First make it work, then make it better"* About the number of local ints: if less than 1 (so none), why even bother with loading `ESP`?